# Exclude one array from the other

Tags: php

I have these two arrays, they have ID [3 and 4] as common and ID [10] as difference. I only need the item with ID [10]

```
<?php

$usergroups = array();
$usergroups[] = array("id" => 3, "name" => "Parish 3");
$usergroups[] = array("id" => 4, "name" => "Parish 4");

$u= (object) $usergroups;
var_dump($u);


echo '<hr />';


$featuredgroups = array();
$featuredgroups [] = array("id" => 3, "name" => "Parish 3");
$featuredgroups [] = array("id" => 4, "name" => "Parish 4");
$featuredgroups [] = array("id" => 10, "name" => "Parish 10");

$fg = (object) $featuredgroups;
var_dump($fg);

  $filtered = array_diff($featuredgroups, $usergroups);
  var_dump($filtered); //returns empty result
?>
```

How do I filter out the featured from  the users? I have tried this

```
$filtered = array();
foreach($u as $uu)
{
   $ug = (object) $uu;
   foreach($fg as $ff)
   {
      $fgr = (object) $ff;
      if($fgr->id != $ug->id)
         echo "<br>---".$fgr->name;  //am supposed to add this to filtered
   }
}
```

and it's printing out

```
---Parish 4
---Parish 10
---Parish 3
---Parish 10
```

instead of just 'Parish 10' which is the difference.

### Update

For some reason, `array_diff`as suggested in the answer did not work. This only worked for linear/1-dimensional array. I tried it with multidimensional array, like the one in the question, it didn't work

```
  $filtered = array_diff($featuredgroups, $usergroups);
  var_dump($filtered); //returns empty result
```

Comment: atleast check the manuel a little bit. `array_diff()` Its in the name.

Comment: am sorry for this - am not allowed to surf the web for that long. Thanks all.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason, this only worked for linear/1-dimensional array. I tried it with multidimensional array, like the one in the question, it didn't work

Comment: You DO NOT have a multi dimensional array. In the question, there is an object which contains the *1 dimensional* arrays who has an int, and a value in its keys. Can you show how you implemented it?

Comment: the first array contains two arrays, and the second contain 3 arrays. I converted both to object to match what joomla gives me. I tried array_diff with one array as $numbers [1..7] and $odd = [1,3,5,7]. array_diff($numbers, $odd) gave me the even numbers and that worked. Applying it to array in question did not work. Am missing anything?

Comment: show how you wrote it. trick is there.

Comment: I updated the question: `$filtered = array_diff($featuredgroups, $usergroups);` returns empty array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the difference of two arrays you can use array_diff.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```
$differences = array_diff($usergroups, $featuredgroups);
```

Comment: Sorry, for some reason, this only worked for linear/1-dimensional array. I tried it with multidimensional array, like the one in the question, it didn't work

Comment: See if array_diff_assoc better fits your needs.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `array_diff`, here's the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the two arrays.

```
            $usergroups = array();
            $usergroups[] = array("id" => 3, "name" => "Parish 3");
            $usergroups[] = array("id" => 4, "name" => "Parish 4");
```

And

```
            $featuredgroups = array();
            $featuredgroups [] = array("id" => 3, "name" => "Parish 3");
            $featuredgroups [] = array("id" => 4, "name" => "Parish 4");
            $featuredgroups [] = array("id" => 10, "name" => "Parish 10");
```

Now, assuming this`id` as unique, we can retrieve all the `id`s in usergroups in an array.

```
foreach ($usergroups as $item => $value)
        {
            $c[] = $value['id'];
        }
```

This $c array will contain all the `id`s in usergroups. Now we all need to do is, check if that `id` is present in featuredgroup; If NOT present, then retreive those values. Which can be done by a combination of `foreach` and `in_array()` in the following way:

```
foreach ($featuredgroups as $item => $value)
            {
                if (!in_array($value['id'], $c))
                {
                    $d[] = $value;
                }
            }
```

**Full code:**

```
foreach ($usergroups as $item => $value)
            {
                $c[] = $value['id'];
            }

foreach ($featuredgroups as $item => $value)
            {
                if (!in_array($value['id'], $c))
                {
                    $d[] = $value;
                }
            }
```

Here `$d` will retrieve the desired result.